# How to change position in onSetContentView while Using Ratio Resolution policy in Andengine

Tags: android, admob, andengine

I am developing (Learning to build :) ) a game with andengine GLES1. I overrides the setContentView to place my admob ad.
Every thing works fine except the resolution policy. I cannot place my ad the way I wanted. as My game is in landscape mode i want the ad to be placed on right and ad will be in Portrait mode. So I tried to use relative layout instead of Frame. Here's my code

```
final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
        mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER);

        final android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams);
        surfaceViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);


        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);        
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a151e9960c73925");
        adView.refreshDrawableState();
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
        frameLayout.addView(adView);
        relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
        this.setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutLayoutParams);
```

but it not showing the ad anymore. please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is any admob banner in portrait mode. See [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android-sizes) and [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners).